# Does a vinegar bandana help against tear gas?

Tags: physiology, vinegar

In the context of the "occupy" protests, I've head a couple of times that you should carry a bandana or cloth soaked in vinegar with you, and in case the police uses tear gas/irritants, you should breath through it, or cover your face with it.

[Here is one recent source](http://gizmodo.com/5853582/how-to-be-a-citizen-journalist-without-getting-killed).

Setting aside legal and moral aspects of preparing for such a situation, say you have a good reason... (and also the fact that is stinks...):

**Does it work? If so, how?**

I'd actually expect the contrary. The vinegar vapors would open up your airways and you would be incapacitated even faster.

Comment: What kind of tear gas do they use? In West-Germany in the 80ies, there was the older CN-Gas, and a more aggressive CS-Gas in use. The myth of vinegar was known then, and known to be a myth, but I don't have any source - we didn't use the Internet over then. :)

Comment: I know in WWI, soldiers in trenches would urinate on their handkerchiefs when there was a chlorine or mustard gas attack. The water reacted with the chloride ions to produce HCl (hydrochloric acid), which was pretty much what happened in the lungs of the target. I leave this as a comment because I don't know what chemicals are used in tear gas and don't know if there's a similar reaction.

Comment: "incapacitated" is probably the less funny but more appropriate word choice. "decapacitation" appears to be a Biology term involving sperm.

Comment: @user unknown, good question. I think in Germany they mostly use pepper/capsicum spray (fired by hand from spray bottles/guns), or CS/CN/pepper, depending on the state, mixed into the water in water cannons. Classic gas grenades are rare, probably because it is hard to control where it goes in an urban setting. I have no idea what's used in the US, I assume some sort of Mace (containing CN)....

Comment: the cloth and moisture alone would probably block at least some of the aerosol (not a gas, this is an aerosol) that is the "tear gas". So it would be somewhat effective of preventing inhalation, but of course have no effect whatsoever on the irritant effect on your exposed skin and eyes. And as an aside, carrying a wet cloth with you for potentially hours guarantees that the cloth will not stay wet :)

Comment: Having been in CS gas while training for the army I can say this wouldn't work. CS gas will sting painfully any exposed flesh that it damp. It will sting you mouth, nose and throat but also you eyes, you armpits, your crotch, any scratches on your hands. Even if the vinegar works, you'd have to bath in it and wear the bandanna over your eyes.

Comment: It helps, so does water. The idea is that it reacts on your face/in the bandana rather than in your throat and lungs. It doesn't prevent it all from getting through, and it burns your face, but I'd take it over a lung full of gas any day.

Comment: @jdm: Grenades where used at the airport Frankfurt (Startbahn West) and at Wackersdorf, where a nuclear reprocessing plant was planned, it wan't much of an urban area. They threw them from helicopters, for example.

Comment: Cleanup involves base and sulfhydryls. That's a lot nastier than vinegar, so vinegar would be used, if it worked:



"CS contamination can be removed by washing with an alkaline solution of water and 5% sodium bisulfite." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS_gas

Answer (score 7):

Tear Gas is acidic, so is vinegar, so vinegar won't neutralize tear gas (if that's the thinking behind using vinegar).

Greek protesters use the indigestion remedy [Maalox](http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/medicines/100001559.html) as an antidote to tear gas, indigestion remedies neutralize acid.

Sources:

[BBC News Report](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/from_our_own_correspondent/9528003.stm)

[Properties of CS Gas - Royal Society of Chemistry's ChemSpider Database](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.16644.html)

[Properties of acetic acid (vinegar) - Royal Society of Chemistry's ChemSpider Database](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.171.html)

[Properties of Magnesium hydroxide (the principal ingredient of Maalox) - Royal Society of Chemistry's ChemSpider Database](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.14107.html)